# How to split a list based on sum of each item length in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There is a table like

```
 Id     Item
--------------------
  1     xx
  2     xx
  3     xxx
  4     xxx
  5     xxx
  6     xxxx
  7     xxxx
```

I want split item column into several groups based on sum of their string length. If group's max length(item) is 6, the result is

```
 Id     Item    GroupId
------------------------
  1     xx         0
  2     xx         0
  3     xxx        1
  4     xxx        1    
  5     xxx        2
  6     xxxx       3
  7     xxxx       4
```

It's easy to accomplish it with cursor or C# code, but cursor is slow and C# code requires extra deployment. I wonder if it is achievable with T-SQL only.

I've tried `(SUM(LEN(item)) OVER(ORDER BY ID) - 1)/6 AS GroupId`, but it doesn't work for Id = 6 and Id = 7 above.

```
 Id     Item    RunningSum   GroupId
--------------------------------------
  1     xx         2            0
  2     xx         4            0
  3     xxx        7            1
  4     xxx        10           1
  5     xxx        13           2
  6     xxxx       17           2
  7     xxxx       21           3
```

Comment: Do you still want solution? :)

Comment: @NEER, I don't work on related project anymore. But I DO want to know the answer.

Comment: But, doesn't _(sum(len(item)) over(order by id))/6_ give you the expected result?

Comment: I don't think it achievable in sql. How is a row grouped is highly depending on all previous rows. It's not a way to think of set, while SQL is good at set. C# or cursor is better option in such situation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the modulus operator to get what you were looking for:

```
select id
, item
, sum(CaseMod) OVER (ORDER BY id) as GroupID
FROM (
  select id
    , item
    , sum(len(item)) over (order by id) as RunTotal
    , sum(len(item)) over (order by id) % 6 as Mod6
    , CASE WHEN sum(len(item)) over (order by id) < 6 THEN 0 
           WHEN sum(len(item)) over (order by id) % 6 <> 0 THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 END AS CaseMod
  from dbo.test
  group by id, item
  ) x 
GROUP BY id, item, CaseMod
```

Here's the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/77b2f/14)

Comment: your answer works with specific sample data provided in question. If there are items of length = 2, or I want to change 6 to 7, it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work with length of 2 values, but you can change the value for the modulus operation as well.  Or make it a variable and pass it in.

Comment: Try http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/77b2f/19. There should be 2 groups. Thank you for the answer all the same.

Comment: So, you're basically treating the items as one huge string and every 6th character need to increment a group value?  Or, if any value between the current record and previous record are divisible by 6, it increments the group id.